# how to make queries to db in custom script using zen cart?

Tags: php, mysql, zen-cart

hi i have a custom script that I call with ajax to retrieve some db info but for some reason it will not allow me to make the calls from this file. yet when i put the code in a page in the templates diretory lets say tpl_products_all_default.php they run fine. what do i need to do to be able to run queries from a custom script?

```
$sql = "select products_model from products where products_model = :productMdel:"; 
$sql = $db->bindVars($sql, ':productMdel:', 'C021', 'string'); 
$result = $db->Execute($sql); 

if ($result->RecordCount() > 0) { 
  echo 'Model number = ' . $result->fields['products_model']; 
} else { 
  echo 'Sorry, no record found for product number ' . $theProductId; 
}
```

Comment: Well you shouldnt put it in the view layer (template), thats for sure. Ive never used Zen or osCommerce, but i would search the documentation for how to develop a plugin, module, or component - whatever they like to call it. Thats usually going to give you the basics of how you **should** go about it.

Answer (score 3):

I may have an answer for you, though I'll admit it's not an optimal setup as it requires your custom file to be placed into the root directory.

If your custom file is being placed in the root (/your_custom_file.php) you can do the following to get access to the $db with the following require statement:

```
require('includes/application_top.php');
```

This will initialize all of the globals, and also call the includes/initsystem.php, which will spin through the values in the autoloader and include each script. The auto_loader can be viewed at includes/auto_loaders/config.core.php.  In v1.5, you can see it finally includes the init_database.php script on lines 81-82. The init_database.php file finally initializes $db.

I initially ran into the same issue you had, and almost missed this setup because I had originally added my custom files to a custom directory like /my_module_extensions/my_file.php which failed. It seems the application_top.php loads everything with relative paths, so when executing under a directory other than the root, it would fail.

I hope this helps!

EDIT: Originally thought you were talking about an admin customization. I reworded this to relate to the public side. This also works from the admin side, if you need to extend the admin console.

Comment: This is the right answer.  Also remember that if the logic shown above is in a function (in a file in the root directory), you need to do a `global $db;`.

Answer (score 0):

Not true you can use an include from anywhere.
such as: 
require_once('inc/php/application_top.php');
or
require_once('http://example.com/inc/php/application_top.php');